# 2 Errors: illegal start of expression [Java]

Tags: java

I haven't finished this but no point progressing if I already have an error. Here is my code..

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of student ==> ");
    studentName = inputDevice.nextInt();
    inputDevice.nextLine();
    System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName " out of 65 ==> ");
    studentMark = inputDevice.nextInt();
    inputDevice.nextLine();
}
```

**1st error:** ')' expected

`System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName " out of 65 ==> ");`

**2nd error:** illegal start of expression

`System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName " out of 65 ==> ");`

I'm very new lol. I don't understand why my second print is giving me an error

Comment: `studentName` should be `String studentName`, `studentMark` should be `int studentMark`, no? Also, you never assign the return value of `nextLine()` to anything...

Comment: Woah, 5 out of 7 lines are faulty or not required. I wrote you up a list of all the issues so you can hopefully understand and fix them and - more importantly - prevent those in the future. However, next time, please get yourself a coffee and carefully read your code (and the error messages) to identify some of these issues yourself before asking on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, *almost everything* is wrong here.

**Issue #1 - line 3**

```
studentName = inputDevice.nextInt();
```

You did not properly declare `studentName`. You are also trying to get an `int` when you want a name (`String`). Instead this line should read:

```
String studentName = inputDevice.nextLine();
```

**Issue #2 - line 4**

```
inputDevice.nextLine();
```

What's this line doing here? You're not assigning the input to anything. Just remove this line entirely.

**Issue #3 - line 5**

```
System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName " out of 65 ==> ");
```

You are missing a `+`. This line should read:

```
System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName +" out of 65 ==> ");
```

**Issue #4 - line 6**

```
studentMark = inputDevice.nextInt();
```

Again, you didn't declare that variable correctly. It should be:

```
int studentMark = inputDevice.nextInt();
```

**Issue #5 - line 7**

```
inputDevice.nextLine();
```

Just like issue 2, this line achieves nothing. Remove it.

**Summary**

Your code should (probably) read like this instead:

```
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of student ==> ");
    String studentName = inputDevice.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName + " out of 65 ==> ");
    int studentMark = inputDevice.nextInt();
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName " out of 65 ==> ");
```

with

```
System.out.printIn("Enter the mark for student "+ studentName +" out of 65 ==> ");
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you didn't declare variables as you should.
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

`String studentName = inputDevice.nextLine();
 int studentMark = inputDevice.nextInt();`